# Triggering led on specific message in aws iot

Tags: python, aws-iot

I am using AWS IoT and Raspberry Pi to glow an LED, but whenever I send *any* message from AWS to the Raspberry Pi the LED glows. And I want to glow the LED on only a particular message.

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste your code in rather than attaching an image of the code. It makes it much easier to help you with the problem. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Use a specific topic for your LED, and send at the payload the message (could be just a bit) to turn it on or off.
Here is the documentation about how topics work: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html